# Bootstrap 4.6 - responsive vertical pills and horizontal tabs (selected tab not being highlighted)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.6

I am creating a page that consists of vertical pills and horizontal tabs. I have managed to get the vertical pills and horizontal tabs to display, but there is an issue with the horizontal tabs - in that the styling doesn't change when a tab is selected.

Here is my HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  /* temp */

  .profile-posts .navbar {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 60px;
  }

  .profile-posts .navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  }

  .profile-posts .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .profile-posts .nav-tabs > .profile-posts li.active > a:focus, .profile-posts .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile-posts tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist"
        aria-orientation="vertical">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href=
          "#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true"
          name="v-pills-home-tab">Foo</a> 

          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab"
          data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls=
          "v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false" name="v-pills-profile-tab">Bar</a>
          
          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href=
          "#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected=
          "false" name="v-pills-messages-tab">FooBar</a>

          <a class="nav-link" id=
          "v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab"
          aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false" name=
          "v-pills-settings-tab">FoofooBar</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>

              <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>

              <li><a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul><!-- Nav tabs content -->

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="first" class="tab-pane active">
                Menu 1 items
              </div>

              <div id="second" class="tab-pane">
                Menu 2 items
              </div>

              <div id="third" class="tab-pane">
                Menu 3 items
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
            Bar
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
            FooBar
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
            FoofooBar
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix the HTMl so that the selected tab is highlighted correctly (also, currently, the spacing between the tabs is a bit "off" - I suspect, this is a CSS styling issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This Class for `nav-tabs > a` tag `nav-link`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  /* temp */

  .profile-posts .navbar {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 60px;
  }

  .profile-posts .navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  }

  .profile-posts .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .profile-posts .nav-tabs > .profile-posts li.active > a:focus, .profile-posts .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile-posts tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist"
        aria-orientation="vertical">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href=
          "#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true"
          name="v-pills-home-tab">Foo</a> 

          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab"
          data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls=
          "v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false" name="v-pills-profile-tab">Bar</a>
          
          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href=
          "#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected=
          "false" name="v-pills-messages-tab">FooBar</a>

          <a class="nav-link" id=
          "v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab"
          aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false" name=
          "v-pills-settings-tab">FoofooBar</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#first" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>

              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>

              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#third" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul><!-- Nav tabs content -->

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="first" class="tab-pane active">
                Menu 1 items
              </div>

              <div id="second" class="tab-pane">
                Menu 2 items
              </div>

              <div id="third" class="tab-pane">
                Menu 3 items
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
            Bar
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
            FooBar
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
            FoofooBar
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```